# IntelliSense doesn't show array indexer on DataSet.Tables[]

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, intellisense, indexer

I'm using VS2013 Community Version 12.0.31101.00 Update 4 (c# in current project)
When I try to use indexer on the DataSet.Tables[] collection (DataTableCollection) and opening square brackets IntelliSense doesn't show me overloaded version of this indexer. 
There are 3 version of this indexer :

```
public DataTable this[int index] { get; }
public DataTable this[string name] { get; }
public DataTable this[string name, string tableNamespace] { get; }
```

I should be able to see them when I open square brackets. Why do they not appear ?

Thanks

Comment: You could try going into 'Options > All Languages > Statement Completion'

Comment: It may also happen that, you have syntax error on some other code line and so it's not coming up.

Comment: @Sean
I think you meant Tools > Options > Text Editor > All languages > Statement Completion. I have enabled all check boxes there excluding 'Hide advanced members'. Problem is unsolved

Comment: That's the one. Sorry, I'm at work - trying to recall from memory.

Answer (score 1):

I found out why IntelliSense didn't show anything after opening Squere brackets.

Unchecking 'Automatic brace completion' solved my problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Firstly Comment out the line you are trying to write and build the code
if it wont build correct this and try again

if this still doesn't work restart visual studio, occasionally IntelliSense will crash and closing and reopening will restart it (fairly common in vs2012 less so in vs2013 but still happens)

if it still isn't running check your settings in

```
Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> General
    Statement Completion
        Auto List Members
        Parameter Information
```

and

```
Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> IntelliSense
```